# Drupal 7 - wysiwyg & images

Tags: drupal-7, tinymce, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I need to insert images into the copytext of a blogpost. I tried different wysiwyg-editors and different image-plugins, but so far every plugin or editor I tried directly adds an `<img>`-tag into the text.

My problem is, that I want to change the markup of the images when the frontend is rendered. Is there any plugin that does not add an `<img>`-tag, but some short code or so that gets translated into an -tag when the field is rendered, similar to wordpress?

That way I could hook into the process and change the markup of the images...

Comment: You should probably post this on http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Lately I've been working on a combination of these modules to work with customized markup:

- [CustomFilter](http://drupal.org/project/customfilter)
- [BUEditor](http://drupal.org/project/bueditor)
- [Markdown filter](http://drupal.org/project/markdown)
- [Markdown Editor for BUEditor](http://drupal.org/project/markdowneditor)

BUEditor and Markdown filter will give you markup-based input that you can than manipulate via RegEx with CustomFilter.

CustomFilter is kind of confusing and a bit of a pain to use, so be ready to bang your fist into your head a few times, but it's totally worth it.  It' much easier than the alternative, which would be [defining your own custom filter module](http://definitivedrupal.org/node/90/).